# Auto highlight a letter/word in python console

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to highlight a word or a letter in python console automatically when using `input` (i.e. when we are typing , if our desired word to be highlighted is found then highlight it with a given color). Like we see in `iPython`. When we our typing our command in `iPython`, it automatically highlights statements. How can I do that?
I think `os.system` or some other module like [`Pigments`](https://pypi.org/project/Pygments/) may do that job.

Comment: "IPython is BSD-licensed, **open-source** software ..." (from ipython.org; my emph.). So you can *literally* check how it works.

Comment: @usr2564301 Can you help me find highlighting file from https://github.com/ipython/ipython ?

Comment: @usr2564301 I think this is the file https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/lib/lexers.py . But its not nearly human readable

Comment: And I also think that this file contains the code for highlighting:    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py     From line 280